# Showing that $\liminf f_n$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(X, \mathbb{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. We are to proof that: 
$$\liminf f_n, \limsup f_n$$ are measurable.
Here is my proof:
Let $a \in X$
$$\{x\in X:  \limsup f_n(x) \le a\} = \{x \in X: \forall k \in \mathbb{N}:\limsup f_n(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k} \} = \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\{x \in X:\limsup f_n(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k} \} = \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \ge n} \{x \in X: f_m(x)< a+ \frac{1}{k}  \} \in \mathbb{F}$$
Something similar with $\liminf f_n$:
$$\{x\in X:  \liminf f_n(x) \le a\} = \{x \in X: \forall k \in \mathbb{N}:\liminf f_n(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k} \} = \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\{x \in X:\liminf f_n(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k} \} = \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{m \ge n} \{x \in X: f_m(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k}  \} \in \mathbb{F}$$
Is my proof correct?

Comment: There are a couple of issues. The first equality is not correct. Can you see why?

Comment: @ZachBoyd There must be a problem with $k$?

Comment: The $x\le a$ is not equivalent to $x<a+\epsilon$ for some epsilon, but rather for all epsilon. A counterexample to the "for some" statement is $x=1,a=1/2,\epsilon=1/2$.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Thank you! Now I understand. Is the rest correct?

Comment: I think there are still going to be some errors after you correct that. Perhaps you can edit your answer to include the corrected solution, and we can go from there?

Comment: Great. Second issue: every time there is a quantified variable (such as $x,k,n$ and $m$, it needs to appear in the next expression. So for instance, you should write $f(x)$ so it is clear what your expression means. $k$ is fine, but it is not clear where $n$ and $m$ should go, especially in your last expression.

Comment: @ZachBoyd I think it's done

Comment: Great. It’s much clearer now. The last equality might be valid—if I were grading it, I would probably want some intermediate steps since the equality is not obvious.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Ok, I will think about some possible intermediate steps. Is the first one clear enough? I would also ask about $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$. Shouldn't we use $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, it should be for all. You got it right in the first set of equalities and just forgot to change the second set in the same way.

Comment: @ZachBoyd That's true. Now everything is correct I hope. What about the intermediate steps? What should I add to make to proof clearer?